# The Meta help pages may contain some copy/paste typos

Tags: bug, help-center

My apologies if this is off the mark or I am missing something obvious. I visited the [Meta Help Center](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-meta) and it looks like Stack Overflow cross-pollinated into the Server Fault pages (some text omitted for brevity):

> ***What is "meta"? How does it work?***
>
> - ...Server Fault users to communicate with each other about Server Fault (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies
>     and community decisions)
> - ...Server Fault users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new features),
>     and
> - ...Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community (soliciting feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies
>     that affect the whole network)

I'm thinking it should say *Stack Exchange* instead of *Stack Overflow*.

I had to label as [bug](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bug) but I think its a little strong for this issue. It looks like a few minor typos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The company name is Stack Overflow. [Again](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/).

This change hasn’t reached all parts of the network yet, though and on the bottom right of th page you can still read

> site design / logo © 2018 **Stack Exchange Inc**

But maybe the whole circus is run by multiple monkeys now, with multiple names, for some *enterprisy* reasons.

Comment: Oh my, sorry about that. I think things are confusing at best. I think it was a bad idea to using a legal entity *Doing Business As (DBA)* name there. Only lawyers and judges and maybe an occasional Stack Exchange fanatic can parse it correctly. The majority of the population will surely parse it incorrectly (*q.v.*). Maybe they (Stack {Somebody}) should add links to the *Stack Overflow* names and link back to their Articles of Incorporation so people understand what is going on.